# Add richtextcontentcontrol from word document throw exception

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-contentcontrol

I try to add a richtext content control to my word document but the richtext content control object is faulty and I am not able to apply for e.g tag to this object

the code to add a richtext content control at specific range selection is

```
using (var range = new ReleaseComObject<Range>(myRange))
{
    var contentControl = vstoDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl(range.ComObject, $"PROPERTY{Guid.NewGuid()}");
    contentControl.PlaceholderText = propertyContentControl.Key; //  exception here
}
```

It works flawlessly in some places of the document. For example I create a textbox and in the textbox I have some text. When I select a text and try apply tag to it I call the method above. But for some reason, when the textbox is place in header part of document and at specific position, I received exception.

The exception I received was:

```
This document might not function as expected because the following control is missing: MYCONTROL. Data that relies on this control will not be automatically displayed or updated, and other custom functionality will not be available. Contact your administrator or the author of this document for further assistance.
```

I inspect the generated control and found that its faulty. Some of its properties show error

[image]

btw: ReleaseComObject is a wrapper class to hold the actual object. this class is disposable.
// Definition of eleasecomobject, implement Idisposable

```
public sealed class ReleaseComObject<T> : IDisposable
public ReleaseComObject(T comObject) => this.myComObject = comObject;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What data type is your 'range' variable? (i.e. why do you need to use range.ComObject here?)

Comment: I used a class to hold generic objects and apply dispose pattern and call it like this
`using (var range = new ReleaseComObject<Range>(myRange))
{
    var contentControl = vstoDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl(range.ComObject, $"PROPERTY{Guid.NewGuid()}");
    contentControl.PlaceholderText = propertyContentControl.Key; //  exception here
}
`
// Definition of eleasecomobject, implement Idisposable
// public ReleaseComObject(T comObject) => this.myComObject = comObject;

Just use myRange but same error
btw: myRange is of type interface Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range

Comment: I wrote a very simple example to try to test this, but so far have not been able to force an Exception.  You mentioned that it only fails when you insert a textbox at a "specific position" - what is that position? (Or is it not obvious which positions cause the problem?). Actually quite interesting that the Exception is on the placeholder Assignment, not the control insertion - that would actually happen if the returned object was actually a Word Content Control rather than a VSTO one, because in that case PlaceholderText would be a read-only property. But not obvious why that would happen.

Comment: Yes, as you can see the screenshot in Visual Studio. The contencontrol object is there but faulty. I think the issue happen to a word template where the textbox is in header part. But I create a another word document with same textbox but there is work. So could be a faulty template also. The template can be download from hereif you are interested. https://easyupload.io/hfsclj